# How can I give more space to a preexistent Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, storage

I have dualboot with Windows10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Time ago I installed Ubuntu giving it just 20GB in order to see if I would like the OS. I like it, so I want to give it more space from Windows.

[Here a picture of GParted from a live distro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWIxs.jpg)

I already made a partition (sda8), then formatted it in ext4 and copied the contents of the original Ubuntu partition (sda4) via the Copy function of GParted. Now I don't get what I could possibly do if not to format the two partition and then to reinstall everything from scratch. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This procedure assumes that /dev/sda4 still contains the original bootable Ubuntu installation.**

**Note**: `/dev/sda3`, Windows partition, needs proper shutdown, and possibly `chkdsk` repair.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **delete** /dev/sda8 partition
- **move** /dev/sda4 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda4 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried to delete sda8 and move sda4 to the left. I just can't, or at least graphically :(

Comment: @FDC You must be booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Step #1.

Comment: I already did yesterday, as I said in the post I was from a live distro. By the way I'll try again

Comment: Oh, I missed something yesterday for sure, it solved my problem ahah Everything works though. Thank you!